# Non-numerical citation mark like [Str91] [Samar] [Tro77]

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I am in need of a particular citation style, it is different from the ones offered by `\cite`, `\citep` or `\citet`.

This is how i would like the marks to look like 
[image: Citation marks]

and this is how the bibliography should be.
[image: Bibliography]

I am not referring to the particular `\bibliographystyle` but to the fact that there are personalized names instead of numbers. I am not sure of it, but I believe that these marks were handcrafted.

At present I am using BibTex, but if needed i am ready to move to other tools.

This is an excerpt of my .bib

```
 @article{maietti2009minimalist,
  title={A minimalist two-level foundation for constructive mathematics},
  author={Maietti, Maria Emilia},
  journal={Annals of Pure and Applied Logic},
  volume={160},
  number={3},
  pages={319--354},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{coquand1998realizability,
  title={A realizability interpretation of Martin-L{\"o}f’s type theory},
  author={Coquand, Catarina},
  journal={Twenty-Five Years of Constructive Type Theory},
  year={1998}
}
```

Comment: In case you might want more information the article i took the screenshot from is the first one in the bib example; I have no idea how this could work as other citation style question i found where mostly about tinkering with \citep and \citet.

Comment: a particular that might be relevant is that multiples entries for the same  author and the same year are disambiguated with letters; like in [Joh02a] and [Joh02b].

Comment: one last supplementary info is that, if possible, I would like the explicitly write the [Mark], maybe in a field of the bib file...

Comment: try using `\bibliographystyle(alpha)`

Comment: @barbara thanks, I was looking exactly for this, even if I had some misconception about what I was looking for. 
If you care about turning this into an answer I would accept it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Would you like to convert your comment into an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `bibtex`, you need to supply a `\bibliographystyle`.  this tells `bibtex` which
`.bst` file to apply.

an "alphabetic" style will derive labels using author names and the given date(s).

`\bibliographystyle{alpha}` is the "basic" one.

there are alternatives that provide different arrangement of the publication information, so check with your publisher to see if there is a preference.